# how to implement hook_menu so that it recognizes URL like ?q=myterm, as sent by jQuery autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, hooks

The jQuery UI autocomplete source string expects the search string to be appended to the URL
as mysite/auto/?q=myterm
(see jquery autocomplete doc)

I have written a module that implements hook_menu and it returns the matching records through JSON.
The expected url is mysite/auto/myterm

How should the hook_menu be written so that it recognizes the ?q=myterm

I am using Drupal 7 and have Clean URL

**Edit:** can you explain with an example or use this code:
can you help with an example?

> url localhost/myauto/?q=sometext

```
mymodule_menu(){  
$items['myauto/%'] = array(  
    'title'= 'My example',  
    'page callback' => 'myexample_auto',   
    'page argument' => array('1'),  
    'access callback' => TRUE,  
 );  

myexample_auto($arg){  
...//user $_GET['q'] or drupal_get_query_parameters to get 'sometext' from $arg  
}
```

Comment: hook_menu does not handle the query parameter. You should make the logic in page callback and dispatch the handler in different case.

Comment: How to pass the query parameter to the page callback? Drupal returns Page not found  when visiting with the ?q=myterm

Answer (score 1):

[`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x) don't handle query parameters. It accepts only wildcards.
You can get your query parameters in in your menu callback function and build your own logic by getting parameters as `$_GET['q']` or [`drupal_get_query_parameters()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_get_query_parameters/7.x)